# Example how to send multi documents in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone have a working example (Prefer in VB.NET or C#) how to send multi documents in DocuSign?

Comment: Please read the [docusignapi] tag info http://stackoverflow.com/tags/docusignapi/info

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this C# client for DocuSign
http://nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll/
you can add the nuget package from Visual Studio or get the open C# code from github. There are samples and it's very simple to use.